# How to disable screen capture of the onscreen keyboard in android?

Tags: android, screen, capture

I tried below in my login activity - while it works fine, however it is not able to disable capture of default onscreen keyboard - so it totally defeats the purpose as one can see the entered password from the keyboard presses.

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

I tried making screen capture video using 3rd party apps - and while whole screen shows black but the keyboard and the presses still shows.

Any idea, how I can stop to get the keyboard captured too ??